# Python : Convert Superclass instance to Subclass

Tags: python, super

I am given an object `a` of the class `A`. I do not understand how class `A` works. Furthermore an unknown number of methods throughout the module I am using use `A`. So for all practical purposes `A` is unknown and we can only manipulate an instance of it and one known method, `method2`.

I am given an instance `a`. I want to convert `a` to a class `B` such that it remains identical in every respect except that `method2` (which was present in the original class `A` and prints `a`) now prints `b`. How do I modify the piece of code below to be able to do that ?

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def method2(self):
        print('b')

a.method1() #prints '1'
a.method2() #prints 'a'
print(a[0]) #prints 1
#a = convertAtoB(a)
a.method1() #prints '1'
a.method2() #should print 'b'
print(a[0]) #prints 1
```

I am aware of a previous answer to a similar question which involved using `__getattr__` however when trying the below piece of code:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__a = a

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.__a, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
    
    def method2(self):
        print('b')
```

I got, in the practical problem I am having, the error `TypeError: 'B' object is not subscriptable`.

edit : added a subscript test, as I mentioned above, I don't entirely understand how `A` works or which methods in the imported module need `A` to work.

Comment: Your code works for me (though your `__setattr__()` and `__getattr__()` don't match - you wouldn't be able to get a property you set via `__setattr__()`). The error `'B' object is not subscriptable` occurs when you try to use square-bracket notation (e.g. `B[2]`) and the `__getattribute__()` method is not defined. Is there some code you haven't shown us where that's happening?

Comment: A is from an imported module, I don't know exactly where it is used or how it works. I only realized after trying the code above that it was subscriptable.

Comment: "I want to convert a to a class B such that it remains identical in every respect except that method2 (which was present in the original class A and prints a) now prints b" What *problem do you solve* by doing this? Especially if you don't understand the `A` class in the first place? Also, where do you expect the data to come from for data that is part of `B` but not part of `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reassign object's `__class__` to a new type. I've put comment inside the code: (take care of object initialization yourself if necessary)

```
class A:
    def func_A_1(self):
        return 'func_A_1 is running'

    def func_A_2(self):
        return 'func_A_2 is running'

    def method2(self):
        return 'method2 of class A'


class B(A):
    def method2(self):
        return 'method2 of class B'


obj = A()

print(obj)
print(obj.func_A_1())
print(obj.method2())
print('------------------------------')

# turning object of A to B
obj.__class__ = B
print(obj)

# still have access to A's methods
print(obj.func_A_1())

# This method is now for B
print(obj.method2())
```

output :

```
<__main__.A object at 0x0000012FECFACFD0>
func_A_1 is running
method2 of class A
------------------------------
<__main__.B object at 0x0000012FECFACFD0>
func_A_1 is running
method2 of class B
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't override `__init__`, only override `method2`, and just set `a = B()`. Or:

```py
class B(A):

    def method2(self):
        print('b')

def convertAtoB(a):
    a.method2 = B().method2
    return a

a.method1() #prints '1'
a.method2() #prints 'a'
#a = convertAtoB(a)
a.method1() #prints '1'
a.method2() #should print 'b'
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work by setting :
```
def convertAtoB(a):
        def method2(self):
              print('b')
    a.method2 = method2
    return a
a = convertAtoB(a)
```
However the other answer was more inline with what I was originally aiming for (as it allowed for a `B` subclass).